# Error in ODBC Connection to Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool DB via spark Notebook with pyodbc

Tags: pyspark, odbc, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I have a dedicated Synapse SQL pool, within which I want to Connect to a database. I want to connect to the database using Python running on a pySpark Notebook inside the same Synapse Instance.

I am using the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) to go about this and my code is the following:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:SYNAPSENAME.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Database=DBNAME;Uid=XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#Sample select query
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

I obtained The connection string from the Dedicated SQL pool page in Azure Under Connection Strings/ODBC/ODBC (Includes Node.js) (Azure Active Directory integrated authentication)

However, when I run it I'm getting the following error:

```
OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

I have Tried running the same code with an earlier version of the Driver (13), but get the following error:

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Traceback (most recent call last): pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I believe this at least indicates the driver for v17 is properly installed. I have also changed the UID to be my username jjesus@XXXX.XXX but get the same error code as the first one.

I'm wondering what could be the issue?

- Do I need Password Auth? Surely Synapse should handle all the authentication alread?
- Is this Connection not possible for SQL pools?

Any help would be great,
Joao

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ODBC driver version.

> If your version of the ODBC driver is 17.1 or later, you can use the
> Azure Active Directory interactive mode of the ODBC driver through
> pyODBC.

If the version is fine, try to use the Password in the given connection string:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:{your_server}.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Database={your_database};Uid={your_user_name};Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Refer below helpful links:

[ODBC connection string example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/connect-overview#odbc-connection-string-example)

[Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15)